# ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: aapt.exe finished with non-zero exit value 42

Tags: android, aapt

> Process 'command 'C:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\build-tools\21.1.2\aapt.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 42